# Url.Action generates wierd url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm missing something very trivial here, in all the examples this works in a razor page:

```
'@Url.Action("GetUserUnits", "MvcAccount")'
```

Which should translate to, which I want to use in javascript:

> /MvcAccount/GetUserUnits

But in stead it generates this:

> /?action=GetUserUnits&controller=MvcAccount

Why? I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you post the javascript that uses the call to `Url.Action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bascially you have something messed up with your routings. `@Url.Action` cannot match routing to your action.

This can be caused by lack of default routing defined. Usually you should have it registered on application start in your `Global.asax.cs` file.

For example it could look like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                          
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );
    }
```

Comment: The controller does work (generates json), doesn't that mean that the routes are okay?

Comment: I have exactly that in my global.asax

Comment: Also I had some additional routes that screwed things up..(because i'm mixing aspx and mvc) It works now

Comment: try to change `id = ""` to `id = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: This line was above the default: routes.MapPageRoute("", "", "~/Default.aspx");. Moved it below default and it works. But my default page is broken.

Comment: Your default page is in the 'Home' controller with action 'Index'. Like the route defaults show.

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to go to -> /MvcAccount/GetUserUnits

Use

```
@Html.ActionLink("nameOfyourLink", "GetUserUnits", "MvcAccount")
                   [displayName]     [Action]       [Controller]
```